# Load more searched rows from database using PHP Ajax loading same rows

Tags: php, mysql

I've fetched 5 rows from the database in search.php file and I'm displaying load more button now when I click on load more button then rows are loading but the same rows that is already loaded is loading again and again when I click on load more button.
I want all other rows with respect to search query but not those rows that already loaded.
Here is my codes

search.php

```
<?php include_once 'assets/inc/header.php'; ?>
  <div class="container custom-post-margin">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 px-2 px-lg-3 mt-1 mt-lg-0">
        <nav>
            <ol class="breadcrumb rounded-0 m-0 text-secondary pb-1">
              <h4 class="text-info">Showing result for : <b><?= $_GET['q'] ?></b></h4>
            </ol>
          </nav>
      <!-- Posts Section -->
      <?php  
        include_once $base_upload_url.'config/config.php';
        include_once $base_upload_url.'config/utils.php';
        $util = new Utils();
        $config = new Config();
        $q = $util->testInput($_GET['q']);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_title LIKE :q OR post_excerpt LIKE :q OR post_tags LIKE :q OR post_category LIKE :q AND post_status = :status ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5";
        $stmt = $config->conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(['q'=>'%'.$q.'%','status'=>'publish']);
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      ?>
      <div id="showAllSearchedPost">
        <?php if($result): ?>
          <?php foreach ($result as $row): ?>
            <a href="<?= BASE_URL ?>post/<?= $row['post_slug']; ?>" class="card-link text-secondary openPostLink" id="<?= $row['id'] ?>">
            <div class="card p-lg-4 p-3 mb-3 rounded-0 shadow custom-post-link">
              <img src="<?= BASE_URL ?>uploads/<?= basename($row['post_image']) ?>" alt="User Management System" class="card-img-top img-thumbnail shadow-sm">
              <div class="card-body p-0 py-3">
                <h4 class="card-title text-info font-weight-bold">
                  <?= $row['post_title'] ?>
                </h4>
                <div class="d-inline">
                  <i class="fas fa-user fa-sm"></i> <?= $row['post_author'] ?> | <i class="fas fa-calendar fa-sm"></i> <?= $util->timeInAgo($row['created_at']) ?> | <i class="fas fa-th-list fa-sm"></i> <?= strtoupper($row['post_category']) ?> | <i class="fas fa-comment fa-sm"></i> 15
                </div>
                <div class="card-text mt-2 text-justify">
                  <?= $row['post_excerpt'] ?>
                  <a href="<?= BASE_URL ?>post/<?= $row['post_slug']; ?>" class="badge badge-primary px-2 py-1 openPostLink" id="<?= $row['id'] ?>"><i class="fas fa-book-reader"></i>&nbsp;Read More</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <?php $post_id = $row['id']; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
        <div class="card p-lg-4 p-3 mb-3 rounded-0 shadow">
            <div class="card-body p-0 py-3">
              <h2 class="text-danger text-center py-5">
               ☹ No Result Found! ☹
              </h2>
            </div>
          </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
      </div>

      <?php  
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_title LIKE :q OR post_excerpt LIKE :q OR post_tags LIKE :q OR post_category LIKE :q AND post_status = :status ORDER BY id DESC";
        $stmt2 = $config->conn->prepare($sql2);
        $stmt2->execute(['q'=>'%'.$q.'%','status'=>'publish']);
      ?>
      <div class="m-4 text-center <?= ($stmt2->rowCount() <= 5)?'d-none':''; ?>" id="show_more_main<?= $post_id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="q" id="q" value="<?= $_GET['q'] ?>">
        <a href="#" id="<?= $post_id; ?>" class="btn btn-danger load_more">Load More&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
        <h3 class="text-center text-light lead mt-4" id="loading" style="display:none;">Loading...</h3>
      </div> 

      <!-- Posts Section End -->
    </div>
      <!-- Sidebar Widget Section -->
      <div class="col-lg-4 px-2 px-lg-3">
        <?php 
          include_once 'assets/inc/search_widget.php';
          include_once 'assets/inc/recent_widget.php';
          include_once 'assets/inc/category_widget.php';
          include_once 'assets/inc/tags_widget.php';
          include_once 'assets/inc/subscription_widget.php';
          include_once 'assets/inc/author_widget.php';
          include_once 'assets/inc/follow_widget.php';         
        ?>
      </div>
      <!-- Sidebar Widget Section End -->

    </div>
  </div>
<!-- Footer Section -->
<?php include_once 'assets/inc/footer.php'; ?>
<!-- Footer Section End -->
```

script.js

```
$(document).on("click", ".load_more", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let post_id = $(this).attr('id');
    let query = $("#q").val();
    $("#loading").show();
    $.ajax({
      url: ''+BASE_URL+'assets/php/action.php',
      method: 'post',
      data: { searched_post_id: post_id, query: query },
      success:function(res){
        $("#show_more_main"+post_id).remove();
        $("#showAllSearchedPost").append(res);
      }
    });
  });
```

action.php

```
if(isset($_POST['searched_post_id'])){

        $id = $_POST['searched_post_id'];
        $query = $util->testInput($_POST['query']);

        $searched_post_count = $db->countPostSearch($id, $query);
        $showLimit = 2;

        $data = $db->loadMoreSearchedPost($id, $query, $showLimit);
        $postId = '';

        if($searched_post_count > 0 ){
            foreach ($data as $row) {
            $postId = $row['id'];
            echo '<a href="'.BASE_URL.'post/'.$row['post_slug'].'" class="card-link text-secondary openPostLink" id="'.$row['id'].'">
                <div class="card p-lg-4 p-3 mb-3 rounded-0 shadow custom-post-link">
                  <img src="'.BASE_URL.'uploads/'.basename($row['post_image']).'" alt="User Management System" class="card-img-top img-thumbnail shadow-sm">
                  <div class="card-body p-0 py-3">
                    <h4 class="card-title text-info font-weight-bold">
                      '.$row['post_title'].'
                    </h4>
                    <div class="d-inline">
                      <i class="fas fa-user fa-sm"></i> '.$row['post_author'].' | <i class="fas fa-calendar fa-sm"></i> '.$util->timeInAgo($row['created_at']).' | <i class="fas fa-th-list fa-sm"></i> '.$row['post_category'].' | <i class="fas fa-comment fa-sm"></i> 15
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-text mt-2 text-justify">
                      '.$row['post_excerpt'].'
                      <a href="'.BASE_URL.'post/'.$row['post_slug'].'" class="badge badge-primary px-2 py-1 openPostLink" id="'.$row['id'].'"><i class="fas fa-book-reader"></i>&nbsp;Read More</a></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </a>';

            }
            if($searched_post_count > $showLimit){
                echo '<div class="m-4 text-center" id="show_more_main'.$postId.'">
                        <input type="hidden" name="q" id="q" value="'.$query.'">
                    <a href="#" id="'.$postId.'" class="btn btn-danger load_more">Load More&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                    <h3 class="text-center text-light lead mt-4" id="loading" style="display:none;">Loading...</h3>
                  </div>';
            }

        }
    }
```

And this is db.php

```
public function countPostSearch($id, $q){
            $sql = "SELECT id FROM posts WHERE post_title LIKE :q OR post_excerpt LIKE :q OR post_tags LIKE :q OR post_category LIKE :q AND id < :id AND post_status = :status ORDER BY id DESC";
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(['q'=>'%'.$q.'%', 'id'=>$id, 'status'=>'publish']);
            $row = $stmt->rowCount();
            return $row;
        }
        // Get more post of searched term
        public function loadMoreSearchedPost($id, $q, $limit){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_title LIKE :q OR post_excerpt LIKE :q OR post_tags LIKE :q OR post_category LIKE :q AND id < :id AND post_status = :status ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit";
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(['q'=>'%'.$q.'%', 'id'=>$id, 'status'=>'publish']);
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        }
```

I've tried everything but unfortunately I did not able to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look carefully at your SQL statement in `loadMoreSearchedPost()`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_title LIKE :q OR post_excerpt LIKE :q OR post_tags LIKE :q OR post_category LIKE :q AND id < :id AND post_status = :status ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit";
```

Your `WHERE` clause is evaluating like this:

```
WHERE
    post_title LIKE :q
        OR
    post_excerpt LIKE :q
        OR
    post_tags LIKE :q
        OR
    ( post_category LIKE :q AND id < :id AND post_status = :status )
```

You should change it to:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE ( post_title LIKE :q OR post_excerpt LIKE :q OR post_tags LIKE :q OR post_category LIKE :q ) AND id < :id AND post_status = :status ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit";
```

Same for the SQL statement in `countPostSearch()`:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM posts WHERE post_title LIKE :q OR post_excerpt LIKE :q OR post_tags LIKE :q OR post_category LIKE :q AND id < :id AND post_status = :status ORDER BY id DESC";
```

should be

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM posts WHERE ( post_title LIKE :q OR post_excerpt LIKE :q OR post_tags LIKE :q OR post_category LIKE :q ) AND id < :id AND post_status = :status ORDER BY id DESC";
```